# Same asked a different way this time the StringConverter is acting up

Tags: javafx

Books.java

```
`final class Books extends Group {

private TableView table = new TableView();
private ObservableList<Book> data;
//private ObservableList<Person> plist;

final HBox hb = new HBox();
final TextField Title = new TextField();
final TextField Author = new TextField();
final TextField Publisher = new TextField();
final TextField Copywrite = new TextField();
final TextField ISBN = new TextField();
final Boolean CheckedOut = false;
final Label Whom;
final Button addButton = new Button("Add");
Boolean FirstRead = true;
//StringConverter<Person> converter;

public final class Book {

    private final SimpleStringProperty title;
    private final SimpleStringProperty author;
    private final SimpleStringProperty publisher;
    private final SimpleStringProperty copywrite;
    private final SimpleStringProperty isbn;
    private final BooleanProperty checkedout;
    private final SimpleStringProperty who;

    Book(String Titl, String Auth, String Publ,
            String Cpywrit, String IsBn, Boolean ChkdOut, String WHO) {

        this.title = new SimpleStringProperty(Titl);
        this.author = new SimpleStringProperty(Auth);
        this.publisher = new SimpleStringProperty(Publ);
        this.copywrite = new SimpleStringProperty(Cpywrit);
        this.isbn = new SimpleStringProperty(IsBn);
        this.checkedout = new SimpleBooleanProperty(ChkdOut);
        this.who = new SimpleStringProperty(WHO);
    }

    public boolean isCheckedOut() {
        return checkedout.get();
    }

    public void setCheckedOut(boolean international) {
        this.checkedout.set(international);
    }

    public BooleanProperty isCheckedOutProperty() {
        return checkedout;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title.get();
    }

    public void setTitle(String Title) {
        title.set(Title);
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author.get();
    }

    public void setAutor(String Author) {
        author.set(Author);
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher.get();
    }

    public void setPublisher(String Publisher) {
        publisher.set(Publisher);
    }

    public String getCopywrite() {
        return copywrite.get();
    }

    public void setCopywrite(String Copywrite) {
        copywrite.set(Copywrite);
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn.get();
    }

    public void setIsbn(String ISBN) {
        isbn.set(ISBN);
    }

    public Boolean getIo() {
        return checkedout.get();
    }

    public void setIo(Boolean CheckedOut) {
        checkedout.set(CheckedOut);
    }

    public String getWho() {
        return who.get();
    }

    public void setWho(String Who) {
        who.set(Who);
    }

    public String isWhoProperty() {
        return getWho();
    }
}

public Books(final File User) throws IOException {

    this.Whom = new Label("inLibrary");
    this.data = FXCollections.<Book>observableArrayList(
            (Book bk) -> new Observable[]{bk.isCheckedOutProperty()
            });

    PhoneList list = new PhoneList(User);


    final Label label = new Label("Book List");
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));
    table.setPrefSize(600, 400);
    table.setEditable(true);
    TableColumn nameCol = bookName();
    TableColumn authorCol = bookAuthor();
    TableColumn publisherCol = bookPublisher();
    TableColumn copywriteCol = bookCopywrite();
    TableColumn isbnCol = bookISBN();
    TableColumn<Book, Boolean> ioCol = ioCol();

///// START work area
    final TableColumn whoCol;
    whoCol = new TableColumn<>("Who to");
    whoCol.setMinWidth(100);
    whoCol.setEditable(true);
    whoCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("who"));
    whoCol.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(list.phonelist));

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //whoCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("who"));
    //whoCol.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.<String, Person>forTableColumn(converter, plist));
    //whoCol.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(list.phonelist));

    /*       
     whoCol.setOnEditCommit((TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Book, String> t) -> {
     ((Book) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
     t.getTablePosition().getRow()))
     .setWho(t.getNewValue());
     try {
     writeFile(User);
     } catch (IOException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(Books.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
     });
     */
//// END work area
    AddBook(nameCol, authorCol, publisherCol, copywriteCol, isbnCol, ioCol, whoCol, User);

    data.addListener((javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Book> change) -> {
        while (change.next()) {
            if (change.wasUpdated() && FirstRead != true) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("List changed");
                    writeFile(User);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Books.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    final VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setSpacing(5);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table, hb);
    getChildren().addAll(vbox);
    try {
        readFile(User);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Books.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private TableColumn<Book, Boolean> ioCol() {
    final TableColumn<Book, Boolean> ioCol = new TableColumn<>("In/Out");
    ioCol.setMinWidth(50);
    ioCol.setEditable(true);
    ioCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("isCheckedOut"));
    final Callback<TableColumn<Book, Boolean>, TableCell<Book, Boolean>> iocellFactory = CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(ioCol);
    ioCol.setCellFactory((TableColumn<Book, Boolean> column) -> {
        TableCell<Book, Boolean> iocell = iocellFactory.call(column);
        iocell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        return iocell;
    });
    ioCol.setCellFactory(iocellFactory);
    return ioCol;
}

private TableColumn bookISBN() {
//Column ISBN Number
    TableColumn isbnCol = new TableColumn("ISBN #");
    isbnCol.setMinWidth(100);
    isbnCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<>("isbn"));
    isbnCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    return isbnCol;
}

private TableColumn bookCopywrite() {
//Column Copywrite
    TableColumn copywriteCol = new TableColumn("Copywrite");
    copywriteCol.setMinWidth(100);
    copywriteCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<>("copywrite"));
    copywriteCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    return copywriteCol;
}

private TableColumn bookPublisher() {
//Column Publisher
    TableColumn publisherCol = new TableColumn("Publisher");
    publisherCol.setMinWidth(100);
    publisherCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<>("publisher"));
    publisherCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    return publisherCol;
}

private TableColumn bookAuthor() {
//Column Author
    TableColumn authorCol = new TableColumn("Author");
    authorCol.setMinWidth(100);
    authorCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<>("author"));
    authorCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    return authorCol;
}

private TableColumn bookName() {
// Column Name
    TableColumn nameCol = new TableColumn("Title");
    nameCol.setMaxWidth(100);
    nameCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<>("title"));
    nameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    return nameCol;
}

private void AddBook(TableColumn nameCol, TableColumn authorCol, TableColumn publisherCol,
        TableColumn copywriteCol, TableColumn isbnCol, TableColumn ioCol, TableColumn whoCol, final File User) {
    table.setItems(data);
    table.getColumns().addAll(nameCol, authorCol, publisherCol, copywriteCol, isbnCol, ioCol, whoCol);

    addButton.setOnAction(
            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                    addBook();
                    try {
                        writeFile(User);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Books.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }

                private void addBook() {
                    data.add(new Book(
                                    Title.getText(),
                                    Author.getText(),
                                    Publisher.getText(),
                                    Copywrite.getText(),
                                    ISBN.getText(),
                                    CheckedOut,
                                    Whom.getText()
                            ));

                    Title.clear();
                    Author.clear();
                    Publisher.clear();
                    Copywrite.clear();
                    ISBN.clear();
                }
            });

    hb.getChildren().addAll(Title, Author, Publisher,
            Copywrite, ISBN, addButton);
    hb.setSpacing(10);
    Title.setPromptText("Tile of Book");
    Title.setMaxWidth(nameCol.getPrefWidth());

    Author.setMaxWidth(authorCol.getPrefWidth());
    Author.setPromptText("Author");

    Publisher.setMaxWidth(publisherCol.getPrefWidth());
    Publisher.setPromptText("Publisher");

    Copywrite.setMaxWidth(copywriteCol.getPrefWidth());
    Copywrite.setPromptText("Year Copywrite");

    ISBN.setMaxWidth(isbnCol.getPrefWidth());
    ISBN.setPromptText("ISBN #");
}

private void writeFile(File User) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(User + "/Books.txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(bw);

    if (table.getItems() != null) {
        data.stream().map((data1) -> {
            if (data1.getTitle().equals("")) {
                data1.setTitle("No_Title");
            }
            return data1;
        }).map((data1) -> {
            if (data1.getAuthor().equals("")) {
                data1.setAutor("No_Author");
            }
            return data1;
        }).map((data1) -> {
            if (data1.getPublisher().equals("")) {
                data1.setPublisher("No_Publisher");
            }
            return data1;
        }).map((data1) -> {
            if (data1.getCopywrite().equals("")) {
                data1.setCopywrite("No_Copywrite");
            }
            return data1;
        }).map((data1) -> {
            if (data1.getIsbn().equals("")) {
                data1.setIsbn("No_ISBN");
            }
            return data1;
        }).map((data1) -> {
            if (data1.getWho().equals("")) {
                data1.setWho("InLibrary");
            }
            return data1;
        }).map((data1) -> {
            outFile.println(data1.getTitle());
            return data1;
        }).map((data1) -> {
            outFile.println(data1.getAuthor());
            return data1;
        }).map((data1) -> {
            outFile.println(data1.getPublisher());
            return data1;
        }).map((data1) -> {
            outFile.println(data1.getCopywrite());
            return data1;
        }).map((data1) -> {
            outFile.println(data1.getIsbn());
            return data1;
        }).map((data1) -> {
            outFile.println(data1.getIo());
            return data1;
        }).forEach((data1) -> {
            outFile.println(data1.getWho());
        });
        outFile.close();
    }
}

private void readFile(File User) throws Exception {
    try {
        String name, author, publisher, copywrite, isbn, whom;
        Boolean InOut;
        try (Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(User + "/Books.txt"))) {
            while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
                name = inFile.next();
                author = inFile.next();
                publisher = inFile.next();
                copywrite = inFile.next();
                isbn = inFile.next();
                InOut = inFile.nextBoolean();
                whom = inFile.next();

                data.add(new Book(name, author, publisher, copywrite,
                        isbn, InOut, whom));
            }
        }
        table.setItems(data);

    } //insert catch statements
    catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException AIOOBexception) {
        System.out.println("Array Index is out of bounds");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException IAexception) {
        System.out.println("Divide by zero error");
    } catch (NoSuchElementException NAexception) {
    }
    FirstRead = false;
}
}`
```

PhoneList.java

```
`final class PhoneList extends Group {

private TableView table = new TableView();
final ObservableList<Person> phonelist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
final HBox hb = new HBox();

public PhoneList(final File User) {
    final Label label = new Label("Phone List");
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

    table.setEditable(true);

    TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
    firstNameCol.setMaxWidth(100);
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
    firstNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    firstNameCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    try {
                        ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setFirstName(t.getNewValue());
                        writeFile(User);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(PhoneList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            });

    TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
    lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));
    lastNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    lastNameCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    try {
                        ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setLastName(t.getNewValue());
                        writeFile(User);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(PhoneList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            });

    TableColumn phoneNumCol = new TableColumn("Phone Number");
    phoneNumCol.setMinWidth(100);
    phoneNumCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<>("phoneNum"));
    phoneNumCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    phoneNumCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    try {
                        ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setPhoneNum(t.getNewValue());
                        writeFile(User);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(PhoneList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            });

    TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");
    emailCol.setMinWidth(120);
    emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<>("email"));
    emailCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    emailCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    try {
                        ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setEmail(t.getNewValue());
                        writeFile(User);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(PhoneList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            });

    table.setItems(phonelist);

    table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, phoneNumCol, emailCol);

    final TextField addFirstName = new TextField();
    addFirstName.setPromptText("First Name");
    addFirstName.setMaxWidth(firstNameCol.getPrefWidth());
    final TextField addLastName = new TextField();
    addLastName.setMaxWidth(lastNameCol.getPrefWidth());
    addLastName.setPromptText("Last Name");
    final TextField addPhoneNum = new TextField();
    addPhoneNum.setMaxWidth(lastNameCol.getPrefWidth());
    addPhoneNum.setPromptText("Phone Number");
    final TextField addEmail = new TextField();
    //addEmail.setMaxWidth(emailCol.getPrefWidth());
    addEmail.setPrefWidth(175);
    addEmail.setPromptText("Email");

    final Button addButton = new Button("Add");
    addButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                phonelist.add(new Person(
                        addFirstName.getText(),
                        addLastName.getText(),
                        addPhoneNum.getText(),
                        addEmail.getText()));
                addFirstName.clear();
                addLastName.clear();
                addPhoneNum.clear();
                addEmail.clear();
                writeFile(User);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PhoneList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });

    hb.getChildren().addAll(addFirstName, addLastName, addPhoneNum, addEmail, addButton);
    hb.setSpacing(3);

    final VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setSpacing(5);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table, hb);

    getChildren().addAll(vbox);
    try {
        readFile(User);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PhoneList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private void readFile(File User) throws Exception {
    try {
        String fN, lN, pNum, eMail;
        try (Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(User + "/PhoneList.txt"))) {
            while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
                fN = inFile.next();
                lN = inFile.next();
                pNum = inFile.next();
                eMail = inFile.next();

                phonelist.add(new Person(fN, lN, pNum, eMail));
            }
        }
        table.setItems(phonelist);
    } //insert catch statements
    catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException AIOOBexception) {
        System.out.println("Array Index is out of bounds");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException IAexception) {
        System.out.println("Divide by zero error");
    } catch (NoSuchElementException NAexception) {
    }
}

public void writeFile(File User) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(User + "/PhoneList.txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(bw);

    if (table.getItems() != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < phonelist.size(); i++) {
            outFile.println(phonelist.get(i).getFirstName());
            outFile.println(phonelist.get(i).getLastName());
            if (phonelist.get(i).getPhoneNum().equals("")) {
                phonelist.get(i).setPhoneNum("No_Phone");
            }
            if (phonelist.get(i).getEmail().equals("")) {
                phonelist.get(i).setEmail("No_Email");
            }
            outFile.println(phonelist.get(i).getPhoneNum());
            outFile.println(phonelist.get(i).getEmail());
        }
        outFile.close();
    }
}

public static class Person {

    private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty phoneNum;
    private final SimpleStringProperty eMail;

    Person(String fName, String lName, String pNum, String email) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
        this.phoneNum = new SimpleStringProperty(pNum);
        this.eMail = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String fName) {
        firstName.set(fName);
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String lName) {
        lastName.set(lName);
    }

    public String getPhoneNum() {
        return phoneNum.get();
    }

    public void setPhoneNum(String pNum) {
        phoneNum.set(pNum);
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return eMail.get();
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        eMail.set(email);
    }

    public String getName() {
        String Name = getFirstName() + "_" + getLastName();
        return Name;
    }

    public Observable isWhoProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String Name = getFirstName() + "_" + getLastName();
        return Name;
    }

}

class EditingCell extends TableCell<Person, String> {

    private TextField textField;

    public EditingCell() {
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            super.startEdit();
            createTextField();
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
            textField.selectAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();

        setText((String) getItem());
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void createTextField() {
        textField = new TextField(getString());
        textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0,
                    Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) {
                if (!arg2) {
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem();
    }
}
}`
```

With these two I do have the ComboBoxTableCell working properly... Thank you very much. Now  its time to figure out how to save it to the .txt file.  Hmm can't think of anything more to say - make sure that you also get MykeZ folder and its contents. but this version has all it needs to work so you can add new data if necessary.

```
`final TableColumn<Book, Person> whoCol;
    whoCol = new TableColumn<>("Who to");
    whoCol.setMinWidth(100);
    whoCol.setEditable(true);
    whoCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("who"));
    whoCol.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(list.phonelist));
    whoCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Book, Person>>() {

        public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Book, Person> evt) {
            try {
                evt.getRowValue().setWho(evt.getNewValue().getName());
                writeFile(User);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Books.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });`
```

And were finished Please give your self credit in this postings for the answer, am very happy thank you  your the best

Comment: you will also need the MikeZ folder and its contents, it needs to be on the same level as the src directory. If you try the .jar  you need to place them there too, when downsizing, the input section of Books.java was taken out too - again sorry for this. Wish I knew how to set-up the Hudson, now that would be far easier, ;)

Comment: _Please give your self credit in this postings for the answer_   ->  You're supposed to 'give credit'.  You click the checkmark on the answer you want to accept.  Also, I wouldn't know about your edit if I didn't look.  You should direct a comment to the person you want to notify, like @name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand the question, but you should be doing something like this.

edit: from looking briefly at your code you might be trying to do something like this;

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.ComboBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class ComboBoxTable extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ObservableList<Person> persons = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        persons.addAll(new Person("Jack"),new Person("Jill"),new Person("John"));

        ObservableList<Book> books = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i=1;i<5;i++)books.add(new Book(i*100,new Person("wrong guy")));

        StringConverter<Person> cvrt = new StringConverter<Person>(){
            @Override
            public String toString(Person person) {
                return person.getName();
            }
            @Override
            public Person fromString(String string) {
                return null;
            }
        };

        TableView<Book> tv = new TableView(books);
        tv.setEditable(true);
        tv.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

        TableColumn<Book, Integer> numCol = new TableColumn("Book Num");
        numCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("num"));

        TableColumn<Book, Person> nameCol = new TableColumn("Name");
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("person"));
        nameCol.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.<Book, Person>forTableColumn(cvrt,persons));

        tv.getColumns().addAll(numCol, nameCol);
        StackPane root = new StackPane(tv);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public class Person{
        SimpleStringProperty name;

        public Person(String name) {
            this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }
        //in simple cases you can just do this and not use a string converter
        @Override 
        public String toString(){
            return name.get();
        }
    }

    public class Book{
        SimpleIntegerProperty num;
        SimpleObjectProperty<Person> person;

        public Book(int num, Person person) {
            this.num = new SimpleIntegerProperty(num);
            this.person = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(person);
        }

        public SimpleIntegerProperty numProperty() {
            return num;
        }

        public SimpleObjectProperty<Person> personProperty() {
            return person;
        }
    }
}
```

Look at the TableView, TableColumn, and [ComboBoxTableCell documentation](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/cell/ComboBoxTableCell.html#forTableColumn-javafx.util.StringConverter-javafx.collections.ObservableList-) and pay attention to the `<S,T>`

The reason you're getting a reference to Person is because the ComboBox doesn't know how to convert it to a string.  I put a simple bit of code to override the toString() method for the Person class.  If you don't specify a StringConverter it won't know how to convert and just uses toString() for objects.

Edit again: Look at your Book class, you have StringProperty who and you're trying to store a person in that field.  Look at my code and I use an ObjectProperty`<Person>`.

You can do it your way but override the toString() in the Person class like in my example and don't use a StringConverter.

```
        @Override 
        public String toString(){
            return name.get();
       }
```

Then make your TableColumn like this and use the type `<Book, Person>`

```
    TableColumn<Book, Person> whoCol = new TableColumn<>("Who to");
    whoCol.setMinWidth(100);
    //editable is true for columns by default. 
    whoCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("who"));
    whoCol.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(p.phonelist));
    whoCol.setOnEditCommit((evt) -> {
        evt.getRowValue().setWho(evt.getNewValue().getName());
    });
```

I made an onEditCommit so the Book class will know how to store the Person info.

Comment: Mine looks exactly like that in the project  I see the errors of my post and made the appropriate changes. Thank you for you help and paitents, am definatley missing something, and can't seem to ask the right question.  Can, will, please grab the project from [link]http://myks3d.webhop.me/ForOracleForums/  and tell me in plain  english what I am not seeing and doing wrong??  If this is possible and you are willing. I have custom code that works but I must understand the right way.

Comment: Your code is too big and complicated.  Make the smallest possible code that shows your problem and will compile.  Read here http://sscce.org/

Comment: Ok will take it down to just the single tablecell that contains the comboboxtablecell and the observablelist that it uses and go from there.  I do appreciate your paitence, and help.

Comment: I edited answer.  For your code you should separate it into classes where the class is in a file named Class.java.  It makes them easier to find.  I would generally break everything into smaller classes.

Comment: Thank  you  we are getting closer but;... with this statement: `this.phonelist = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Mike","Bob","Stan","Gary");`  it works , but am trying to get the values from Phonelist.java. I think that am getting a refrence to this, but not populating the list. I have simplified down to only the PhoneList.java and a ComboBoxTableCell in Books.java - where can I put PhoneList .java so you can  view it.

Comment: Just edit your question and add it there.  It won't be much help if there's a bunch of supporting classes.  That's why it's good to provide a SSCCE.